# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/onesignal/ActivityLifecycleHandler$1.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, signed-apk

I am receiving the error when trying to generate a signed apk on android studio.
Research has shown I need to exclude a module to one of the compiled jar files. But I cannot tell which one needs to be excluded.

```
The following is my list of dependancies
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile files('libs/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ical4j-1.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-manipulation_3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/natty-0.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
    compile project(':hijriCalendarLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And this is the full error received:

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/onesignal/ActivityLifecycleHandler$1.class
```

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the issue is with this dependency:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
```

It is using a class named "ActivityLifecycleHandler" , this is the class that producing conflict, there must an other dependency which is using the same class.

Try to find the other dependency which has this class or try to exclude this class from the dependency given above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was because of existing jar file 'OneSignalSDK.jar' in project libs folder.
The problem solved after deleting it.